# Select 2, distinct records from 2 tables, in random order, in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT tb1.id, tb2.id 
FROM tb1
JOIN tb2 ON tb1.group = tb2.id
WHERE 
tb1.status = 1 AND tb2.status = 1
GROUP BY tb1.group
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 2
```

Both tables are small (under 1000 rows), so ORDER BY RAND() is fine.

For every record in tb2, there is 10 records in tb1 (linked by tb2.id = tb1.group). I would like to select 2 distinct groups, with a random record in tb1 for each group.

Having the GROUP BY clause always selects the first record in the group from tb1. Removing the GROUP BY clause, it picks a random one as it should.... but it could select 2 items in the same group every once in a while.

How would I select 2 random records from tb1, in 2 distinct groups?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, this seems more complicated than I think it should be, but I think it meets your requirements:

```
select tb2.*,
       (select tb1.id from tb1 where tb1.group = tb2.id and tb1.status = 1 order by rand() limit 1) 
from tb2
where tb2.status = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from tb1 where tb1.status = 1 and tb1.group = tb2.id)
group by tb2.id
order by rand()
limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading what you are asking for, so let me clarify what I THINK you are asking...
2 random records from tb1 in 2 distinct groups...  For every tb2 record, you want TWO random record from the tb1 table.  so if tb2 has 100 records, you want 200 in the result set... 2 for group #1, 2 for group #2, 2 for group #3, etc..

If so, I would just wrap your query and utilize MySQL variables and put a counter per group and apply a HAVING clause...

```
select
      AllPossible.group,
      @lastSeq := if( AllPossible.group = @lastGroup, @lastSeq +1, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
      @lastGroup = AllPossible.group
   from
      ( SELECT 
              tb1.id, 
              tb2.id 
           FROM 
              tb1
                 JOIN tb2
                    ON tb1.group = tb2.id
           WHERE 
                  tb1.status = 1 
              AND tb2.status = 1
           ORDER BY 
              tb1.group,
              RAND( ) ) AllPossible,
      ( select @lastGroup := 0,
               @lastSeq := 0 ) sqlvars
   having
      GroupSeq < 3;
```

The prequery (aliased "AllPossible" ) still gets your unique qualified status=1 records joined from both tables... however, it puts them all in order of same group first, then random, such as

Grp   Record  Group Seq

```
1     19      1     (keep)
1     95      2     (keep)
1     3       3     (throw away)
1     28      4     (throw away)

2     34      1     (keep)
2     14      2     (keep)
2     89      3     (throw away)
2     41      4     (throw away)

3     9       1     (keep)
3     25      2     (keep)
3     42      3     (throw away)
3     76      4     (throw away)
```

From that, it sequentially assigns a "group sequence".  Since the RAND() is applied first and returned in random order, it just stamps  the records 1, 2, 3, 4, (next group) -- 1, 2, 3, 4 etc...  The having clause finally states I only want those with a group sequence less than 3 thus keeping only 1 & 2 per group throwing out all the rest from the final result set.